# Sourcetree: unable to edit author for a commits ready to push

Tags: gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I've made a lot of changes on a brach and tried to commit them but I get `remote: GitLab: Author '' is not a member of team`

I updated my default details and now when I pull the branch again to another location I can push to it, but in the original place I made the changes I still can't push my changes.

Is there something else I need to do to edit the author on the changes in the push or is it possible to get all my changes back into the unstaged files section so I can at least see my changes and copy them over to my second location?

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with having all the changes as un-committed changes at once, you can undo the commits and keep the changes in unstaged:

`git reset --mixed HEAD~[NumberOfCommitsToReset]`

This will undo the commits but keep the changes as unstaged. You can now stage changes and commit them as you please, giving them the current author.